# Ajax calender is not showing with its text box it is showing in top of screen

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I m using Ajax Calendar extender with text box but calender extender is opening in top of screen not in my textbox where i am using this calendar extender

Answer (score 0):

Goto Design Mode and Click on TextBox and Goto Arrow showing while click and extend the AjaxCalnderExtender....than it show your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild your project. Also try to debug on other browsers. If it works on Google Chrome and not on internet explorer, try resetting your browser. Also make sure you are using the correct .net framework. To do this, use ..

```
Response.Write("Version: " + System.Environment.Version.ToString());
```

Place the above code on your page load to get a exact version you are running. You may also need to place this in your web.config.

```
<add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.30319.18047, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

But where it says Version, put the .net framework version you found out you are using in there instead. I found that sometimes using the wrong framework version then the one installed on the development machine does some goofy things. Sometimes (for me) it caused the issue you are describing or Ajax didn't work at all. Thy those few things and see if one helps! Good luck.